# Angular translate, load init file

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, angular-translate

I am using angular translate as below. But I want to get my global.json loaded just starting, since I only want to have one file per language and that is loaded from the beginning and not every time I load a controller.
Can somebody help me.
Thank you very much.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('01')
    .config(translationConfig);

translationConfig.$inject = ['$translateProvider', 'tmhDynamicLocaleProvider'];

function translationConfig($translateProvider, tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
    // Initialize angular-translate
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: 'app/i18n/{lang}/{part}.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('es');
    $translateProvider.useStorage('translationStorageProvider');
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');
    $translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');

    tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('app/i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
    tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.useCookieStorage();
    tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.storageKey('NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY');
}
})();
```

Controller:

```
resolve: {
      translatePartialLoader: function($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
        return $translate.refresh();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom loader, where you cache your translations

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/13_custom-loaders